# windows folder with millions of files not responding

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

I am using Windows 7 (64-bit) on an Intel Q6600 CPU with 4GB of RAM.

I have a folder with 2 million files, with an average file size of 10 KB.

Windows Explorer stops responding when I open the folder. How can I overcome this?

Comment: By not storing two million files in the same folder...

Comment: To be a little more clear than that comment, I'm not an expert on this but I believe NTFS is simply not designed well for that many files in one folder.  It doesn't scale very well and simply enumerating the contents of the folder can take forEVER.

Comment: Is there a reason why older files aren't being archived?

Comment: did you try disabling thumbnails?

Comment: You know whats even worse.. trying to delete that folder.. good luck :(

Comment: @Shinrai, as Roger notes in his answer, NTFS is fine, it's Explorer that has a lot of work to do when you open the folder.

Comment: @dsolimano - That's why I left answering to folks more knowledgeable than myself. :)

Comment: I have run into similar issues when working with time-lapse movie footage with 20-200k images. What do you want to do with those files? Have you considered using the command-line shell (cmd.exe) to work with the files instead of explorer?

Comment: i ended up by starting over, and partitioning my folders into years and months subfolders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can overcome it by using a more sensible structure for your files.   While Explorer will support directories with millions of files, it isn't designed for this sort of scenario and performance will be slow.

For more info, see this TechNet article from September 2011:

[Windows Confidential: No Limits … Sort Of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/hh395477(v=msdn.10))

Comment: I like Raymond's explanation. I would be angry if Microsoft spent money testing Explorer on such a niche situation.

Comment: imho, official guidelines and/or system warnings would be more appropriate than a (non-)apologetic technet article.

Comment: It just the filesytem restriction.. it was flawed since NTFS was made, then they tried fixing ti with indexing.. but is sitl rubbish, ZFS forward

Comment: It's not a filesystem restriction - it's a display problem.  NTFS can store an unlimited number of files per volume.  The issue is that it's very difficult to build a UI that will display a directory of two million files - and why should MSFT worry about this?   Who's going to page through so many files?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, Windows cannot handle more than 80 thousand files in a folder, neatly and efficiently (On a Xeon 2.8Ghz server with 4GB RAM at least)

It starts to crash and burn near 60k.

At 200k it takes 2 days to enumerate the folder. We had this problem with badmail folder using Windows Exchange. The only way to overcome it is to make thousands of folders (that it can handle fine) with files inside those folders with more folders.

Otherwise you should seriously consider dumping that data into a SQL file, using SQLExpress which is free or MySQL which is also free. Write a small program to handle it and you will be good to go - that's what we did with our 200k files and now we have over 12 million emails sorted, with quick access.

Answer (score -1):

What is amazing that today, October 1 2022, with Windows 11 this behaviour is still the same and MS is not taking care a little bit.
However, there are tools like Total Commander or Cygwin which have no issues at all with high numbers of files.
Of course it makes sense that there are not that many files stored in one directory. But not all tools take care of that hint. I just stumbled over Apples icloud foto stream, which puts all the ~15k fotos of my iPhone into one single directory. It took forever (I lost patience and stopped after 10 mins) to just list the filename, file-date and size w/o any preview or content related stuff (I only wanted to copy a few file from a certain date). Using Total-Commander lists it in a few seconds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).